# Placing items before \documentclass

Tags: packages, document-classes, preamble

When looking in books or at sample code, I always see `\documentclass` appearing first. Is that absolutely necessary?

I have created some test code which seems to compile fine:

```
\def\SetClass{article}
\documentclass{\SetClass}
\begin{document}
    This is some text.
\end{document}
```

Is there any problem with placing other items, such as `\input`, `\usepackage`, or such details before the `\documentclass`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There aren't really problems and in fact some techniques use input before `\documentclass`, for example to set a conditional. One has to be careful not to define commands that can be later defined by the class or a package via `\newcommand` (for instance `\large`).

Of course it would have little sense to set the text width or the text height before `\documentclass`, but it's not disallowed: simply it won't work.

You can even say `\input{file}`, as long as the code in `file.tex` doesn't break the "rule" stated above.

The only command that is formally disallowed before `\documentclass` is `\usepackage`, as pointed out by doncherry. Other commands just *can't* because they would be nonsensical (`\begin{document}` is an example).

Of course, no text producing command should go before `\documentclass`, nor any definition or measurement that relies on document properties such as the default font and size, which are set later. But one can say `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: Well, you can't use `\begin{document}` before `\documentclass`!

Answer (score 18):

You can't use `\usepackage` before `\documentclass`, you'll get an error. There are a few packages recommended to be loaded before it, though, e.g. [`nag`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nag) and [`hyphsubst`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphsubst); you have to use `\RequirePackage` for them.