# What is the general shape of the preamble of a latex main file?

Tags: document-classes

The task is to identify latex main files to write a maven plugin 
processing latex files (conversion into various formats).

Currently, I identify the main file with the pattern

```
.*\\begin\s*\{document\}.*
```

but this is wrong. 
What about

```
\s*\\documentclass.*
```

? 
This would mean that apart from blanks,
`\documentclass` must be the very beginning of the file.

I remember that there was a second possibility: `\documentstyle`?

Comment: `\documentclass` doesn't need to be the first command. There could be `\RequirePackage` or definitions before. Also while nowadays normally every LaTeX file has a `\documentclass`, a main file could also consist simply of an `\input{real-main-file}`.

Comment: In the meantime I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35855/placing-items-before-documentclass.

Comment: Well, you should check for a `\documentclass` or `\begin{document}`, but following any `\input` provided, so that you can't miss it. How detailed do you want your check? A latex main file means you would also have to check that this is not pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex (check for eventually enhanced features).